# How can I convert code with operands %lo %hi to MARS working code?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I don't know how to convert code below to code that would work on MARS. Any ideas? Whole code here: https://pastebin.com/2RRT60Rd

```
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-72
    sw      $31,68($sp)
    sw      $fp,64($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    lui     $2,%hi($LC0)
    addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC0)
    jal     printf
    nop

    addiu   $2,$fp,40
    move    $5,$2
    lui     $2,%hi($LC1)
    addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC1)
    jal     __isoc99_scanf
    nop

    lui     $2,%hi($LC2)
    addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC2)
    jal     printf
    nop

    addiu   $3,$fp,56
    addiu   $2,$fp,48
    move    $6,$3
    move    $5,$2
    lui     $2,%hi($LC3)
    addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC3)
    jal     __isoc99_scanf
    nop
```

Comment: *How should I convert code....

Comment: You would get better feedback if you give more detail, and I think you can find your answer with a little bit of research in Google.

Comment: `lui $2,%hi($LC0) / addiu $4,$2,%lo($LC0)` could be written as `la $4, LC0`. `la` is a pseudo-instruction, and the assembler will take care of translating it into the correct sequence of actual instructions (probably something like that `lui` / `addiu` sequence).

Comment: Of course, you don't have libc functions such as `printf` in the MARS simulator. You'll have the use the appropriate [system calls](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) instead.